# How to cast nulls to blank and those with number to decimal 3 places?

Tags: sql-server, decimal, varchar

If I want the output to be blank if there is no gpa, and rounded to 3 decimal places if there is a gpa - how do I get that in one statement?

Here are the 2 statements I have come up with that I am having trouble combining as one (for blank if answer is null and 3 places decimal if there is a gpa).

decimal 3 places:

```
NULLIF(cast(round(termgpa.gpa, 3) AS DECIMAL(18, 3)), 0)
```

if null then blank:

```
isnull(cast(termgpa.gpa as varchar), ' ')
```

Comment: `NULLIF` returns NULL if both of the strings are equal else returns first string. `ISNULL` is used to replace value of expression, if it comes to NULL.

Comment: Would you know how to combine the 2 into one statement?  So it casts the nulls as blank and if decimal makes it 3 decimal places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a case statement. Also, if you want the column to contain both blanks and decimal numbers you will have to cast it as a varchar. The below statement shows both null and non null.

```
declare @gpa decimal(18,5)

set @gpa = '5.789456'
select 
    case
        when @gpa is null then ''
        else cast(cast(round(@gpa, 3) AS DECIMAL(18, 3)) as varchar)
    end as gpa
--returns 5.789

set @gpa = null
select 
    case
        when @gpa is null then ''
        else cast(cast(round(@gpa, 3) AS DECIMAL(18, 3)) as varchar)
    end as gpa
--returns blank
```

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me see that the case statement would work for me:                       
case when gpa is null then ' ' else cast(cast(round(gpa, 3) AS DECIMAL(18, 3)) as varchar) END AS GPA

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[termgpa](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [gpa] [decimal](18, 3) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[termgpa] ([id], [gpa]) VALUES (1, CAST(20.000 AS Decimal(18, 3)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[termgpa] ([id], [gpa]) VALUES (2, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[termgpa] ([id], [gpa]) VALUES (3, CAST(15.761 AS Decimal(18, 3)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[termgpa] ([id], [gpa]) VALUES (4, CAST(45.650 AS Decimal(18, 3)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[termgpa] ([id], [gpa]) VALUES (5, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[termgpa] ([id], [gpa]) VALUES (6, CAST(78.100 AS Decimal(18, 3)))
GO
```

I have created sample table with just two columns. now you can either choose to covert your decimal column to varchar or you can set 0 instead of null value as follows

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(gpa AS VARCHAR(20)),'') FROM dbo.termgpa
```

or you can set 0 or -1 whenever gpa is null and handle the same in code

```
SELECT CASE WHEN gpa IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE CAST(gpa AS DECIMAL(18,3)) END FROM dbo.termgpa
```